# Equivalent of cosine law to find moment of inertia

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

Similar to how the perpendicular axis theorem is analogous to the Pythagoras' theorem I wanted to find an expression analogous to the cosine law to find the moment of inertia. In other words given two axis $L_1$ and $L_2$ (Slope of the angle between them $= m$) and the moment of inertia of a body with respect to these axis is $I_1$ and $I_2$ respectively. We have to find the moment of inertia with respect to an axis perpendicular to to these axis in terms of the given quantities. I got this expression

$$ \frac 1 {m^2} \left( (I_1+I_2)(1+m^2) + \sqrt{I_1I_2(1+m^2)} \,\right).  $$

Can someone please check this because I am getting wrong answers using this expression.

Comment: What is the “Slope of the angle between them” ?   The angle between the lines is m ?

Comment: @Eli The wording is kinda wrong. What I mean is that if the angle is x then tanx = m

Comment: Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for mathematical expressions.  It is the site standard and greatly improves readability.

Comment: @StephenG ok I did that but was unable to get the fractions to work

Comment: I suggest putting a picture

Comment: @Buraian Just to clarify in case this is what you meant, we actively discourage using pictures of equations - Mathjax is the way to go.

Comment: Comments use the **frac** directive.  I'll edit that in (if someone doesn't beat me to it).  It is OK as it is really - I don't think anyone would have a major issue with it that way.

Comment: Can you also share your derivation, that will make it easier to find out where you went wrong

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You have the line $L_1$ with the inertia tensor $T_{L1}$

$$T_{L1}=\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} { I_1}&0&0\\ 0&0&0
\\0&0&0\end {array} \right] 
$$

and the line $L_2$  with the inertia tensor $T_{L2}$

$$T_{L2}=\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} { I_2}&0&0\\ 0&0&0
\\0&0&0\end {array} \right] 
$$

to obtain the inertia tensor in $x~,y~,z$ perpendicular local system ,you have to transform the inertia tensor $T_{L2}$ with the transformation matrix R (which is a rotation about the z axis with the angle $\alpha$).

thus:

$$T_{xyz}=T_{L1}+R\,T_{L2}\,R^T$$

with

$$R=\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} \cos \left( \alpha \right) &-\sin \left( 
\alpha \right) &0\\ \sin \left( \alpha \right) &\cos
 \left( \alpha \right) &0\\ 0&0&1\end {array}
 \right] 
$$

$$T_{xyz}=\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} I_{{1}}+ \left( \cos \left( \alpha
 \right)  \right) ^{2}I_{{2}}&\cos \left( \alpha \right) I_{{2}}\sin
 \left( \alpha \right) &0\\\cos \left( \alpha
 \right) I_{{2}}\sin \left( \alpha \right) & \left( \sin \left( \alpha
 \right)  \right) ^{2}I_{{2}}&0\\ 0&0&0\end {array}
 \right] 
$$